# Using a pipe to execute cat and grep

Tags: c, pipe

I want to execute `cat` on a file then search for the number of times a string is present in this file using `grep`

My current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

  pid_t pid ;
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);
  pid = fork(); 

  if(pid == 0) {
    // close sdout and redirect output to fd[1]
    close(1);
    dup(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    char *exp[] = {"cat", "filename.txt", NULL};
    if( (execvp("cat", exp)) < 0) {
      perror("Execvp failed from child");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  else if(pid > 0) {
    // close stdin and redirect input to fd[0]
    wait(NULL);
    close(0);
    dup(fd[0]);
    close (fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);

    char *exp[] = {"grep", "-c", "name", "filename.txt", NULL};

    if((execvp("grep", exp)) < 0) {
      perror("Execvp failed from parent");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  else {
    printf("Error in forking");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting an output of 0 which is wrong as the string I am searching for is present in the file and running `grep` from the terminal results in a different output, ani idea on why this is happening and what do do?

Comment: Aren't you closing your pipes input and output streams before the cat and grep can even use them?

Comment: Also why does grep gets the filename a second time? Isn't the purpose of cat to pipe the content of the file to grep?

Comment: But I did `dup` before that, is this wrong?

Comment: well yes and I noticed that but I didn't know how else to do it

Comment: _"well yes and I noticed that but I didn't know how else to do it"_ just remove it, you are essential emulating the bash command `cat filename.txt | grep -c name`

Comment: Thank you, it's now working after I removed it(didn't do anything to the pipes though) do you want to post your answer so I mark it as the correct one?

Comment: You may answer your own question if you found the solution, so just post what you changed as an answer, I don't mind.

Comment: It is simpler and more reliable to use `dup2()` than `dup()`.

Comment: Note that the `wait(NULL);` in the parent is a bad idea.  If the file is too big to fit in the pipe (usually, that means bigger than 64 KiB these days; once upon a time, it was only 5 KiB), then the `cat` will block waiting for something to read the pipe, and the `grep` won't be launched until after the `cat` terminates — deadlock.

Comment: You don't need to test the value returned by `execvp()` or any of the members of the `exec*()` family.  If the function succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, it failed.  You can use `execvp(exp[0], exp);` in both places you use `execvp()`.  It's a good idiom to use.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
  pid_t pid ;
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);

  pid = fork(); 

  if(pid == 0) {
    // close sdout and redirect output to fd[1]
    close(1);
    dup(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    char *exp[] = {"cat", filename.txt", NULL};
    execvp("cat", exp);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  }

  else if(pid > 0) {
    // close stdin and redirect input to fd[0]
    close(0);
    dup(fd[0]);
    close (fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);

   char *exp[] = {"grep", "-c", "name", NULL};
   execvp(exp[0], exp);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  else {
    printf("Error in forking");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

The main fix to the problem was removing the filename from the comments as one user pointed it, this got me a correct output. However, as another user suggested in the comments there was some optimization to be done such that removing the `wait(NULL)` and removing testing for what `exec` returns. Thanks everyone!